# Group names by query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to group all the users name by their groups. I tried :

```
var query = from u in db.Users
            group p by u.UserGroup 
            select u.FullName;
```

How do I work it out?

Answer (score 3):

This will return sequence of anonymous objects, containg UserGroup and all names from that group:

```
var query = from u in db.Users
            group u by u.UserGroup into g
            select new {
               UserGroup = g.Key,
               Names = g.Select(x => x.FullName)
            };
```

Comment: its telling me :Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type C:\Users\Dev4\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Linq\SqlQuery\QueryOnName.cs 17 29 SqlQuery

Comment: @darko you are converting some lambda to string comparer in your QueryOnName method. That is code which produces error